# How do I pull specific data out of text file and add as variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find a way to pull the Path of a certain process that is running.

What I have is two processes that run as the same name. I have a batch script that will look at log files for a specific error that happens from time to time. When that is found I would like to restart that app. Problem is there are multiple of these running so I need to know how to restart the specific one. I have the script that will look for the error and restart. I also found a way to pull the information for each of the processes into a text file. I am stumped from there.

Batch to restart Process:

```
Set Current_Date=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%

findstr /m "OutOfMemoryException" c:\progra~1\APP1\logs\%Current_Date%.log
if %errorlevel%==0 (
   goto Restart_app
) else (
   goto end
)

:Restart_app
set /p PID=<C:\progra~1\app1\app1.txt
taskkill /PID %PID% /T /F

cd "C:\Program Files\APP1"
Start "" "C:\Program Files\APP1\APP"

:end
```

Command to pull information is :

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\progra~1\APP\ProcessList.txt PROCESS where Caption="APP.exe" get Commandline,Processid
```

Here are the results:

```
Caption    CommandLine                                                               ProcessId  
APP.exe  "C:\Program Files\APP2\APP.exe" {FC6B21FF-34A5-4e21-B22E-DD36573B6C10}  3988       
APP.exe  "C:\Program Files\APP1\APP.exe" {89295D77-02D1-4487-95B6-C86E6915C909}  5156
```

Curious how to turn the path and processid into variables that I can use to restart the specific app that is having a problem. Currently I would be killing both apps. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Update:

New Batch file to pull the process ID when starting the App vs pulling information after the app is running per recommendation below . Only problem is when doing so it starts in the C:\program files\System32 directory. I know this due to all log files being added in system32 directory and app will not run as it needs files from its own directory.

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' wmic process call create "c:\program files\app1\app.exe app-parameters" ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set PID=%%a
Echo %PID% > App1.txt
```

Comment: If you are doing complex processing like this in batch files, consider the much more modern and capable PowerShell.

Comment: I'd love to see this script, when complete.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to capture the PID of the executable when it starts, which can be done by launching it with WMIC.  Taskkill can then kill it via PID information.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' wmic process call create "notepad.exe" ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set PID=%%a
echo "%PID%"
pause
```

Comment: This idea works, but I can not figure out how to start the app in a specific folder. It needs to start in its folder vs c:\windows\system32 . Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: It does start in it's own folder, unless you execute it with admin permissions.  Add `cd /d "%~dp0"` to the top of your batch file to force the current working directory.

Comment: So after adding that above the for /f line and launching the app the log files are still being written to c:\windows\system32 folder. This makes me think its still starting in the wrong folder.

Comment: Edit your question and add your code - nobody knows what you have in your batch file at this stage.

Comment: Ok I updated the Batch to restart process as well as adding in the batch that originally starts process and pulls process id on startup.

Comment: It seems that `wmic` defaults to the `system32` folder.

Comment: No way to default it to a new folder or pull the PID when starting another way?

Comment: This issue was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658745/wmic-how-to-use-process-call-create-with-a-specific-working-directory/24658880#24658880 so thanks to MC ND and assuming the parameters works, you just have to use `"c:\program files\app1\app.exe app-parameters","c:\program files\app1"`